# Sanitize rows from database and push to array

Tags: php

I'm trying to get all the rows from my database table, sanitize it and push it to an array. But the htmlspecialchars function is removing the 'keys' from the $row.

Without the htmlspecialchars i get the output like

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [ID] => 4 [IMAGE] => header1.jpg [LINK] => blog
>   [NAME] => rajohan ) )

But with htmlspecialchars i get

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 4 [1] => header1.jpg [2] => blog [3] =>
>   rajohan ) )

Why is it removing everything inside [ ]?

```
function sanitize_array($data) {
    $data = array_map('trim', $data);
    $data = array_map('strip_tags', $data);
    $data = array_map('htmlspecialchars', $data, array(ENT_QUOTES), array('UTF-8'));
    return $data;
}

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    array_push($header, sanitize_array($row)); // Push rows to array
}
```

Comment: You can't pass arguments to htmlspecialchars like this. See the [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) documentation.

Comment: how about instead of calling array map several times you could have sanitize work on one piece of data and call array map outside to sanitize

Comment: I'm, calling this script with ajax to get the data and then plan to encode it with json so i want to sanitize it before the json and javascript handles it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by making another function to pass in the arguments to htmlspecialchars.

```
function htmlspecialchars_array($data) {
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    return $data;
}

function sanitize_array($data) {
    $data = array_map('trim', $data);
    $data = array_map('strip_tags', $data);
    $data = array_map('htmlspecialchars_array', $data);
    return $data;
}

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    array_push($header, sanitize_array($row)); // Push rows to array
}
```